# Using Optionals correctly in service layer of spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I new to spring boot application development. I using service layer in my application, but came across the repository method that return Optional as shown below.

```
 @Override
public Questionnaire getQuestionnaireById(Long questionnaireId) {
    Questionnaire returnedQuestionnaire = null;
    Optional<Questionnaire> questionnaireOptional = questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId);
    if(questionnaireOptional.isPresent()) {
        returnedQuestionnaire = questionnaireOptional.get();
    }
    return returnedQuestionnaire;
}
```

My question is ,

1. whether I am using the Optional correctly here. And is it ok to check this optional (isPresent()) in the RestController and throughing exception is not present.Like below

```java
public Optional<Questionnaire> getQuestionnaireById(Long questionnaireId) {
    return questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId);
}
```

Comment: you can simply return questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId).orElse(null)

Comment: Your first code snippet is just a convoluted null-check, and defeats the whole purpose of `Optional`. Returning an `Optional` means: this method either returns a certain something, or sensibly returns an absent value. For `findById`, it makes sense to return an `Optional`, because the absense of a value is a sensible use case (it's rather common than an exception). You are better off returning the `Optional`, because it forces the caller to think about this use case – the absense of a value.

Comment: Note that question #2 is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go for either option tbh, especially not the first. You don't want to introduce null values inside your domain. Your domain should stay as simple as possible, readable and void of clutter like null checks.

You might want to read through the optional API for all your options, but personally I would go for something like this:

In repository:

```java
public interface TodoBoardRepository {

    Optional<Questionnaire> findByQuestionnaireId(String questionnaireId);

    // ...

}
```

In service:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor // Or generate constructor if you're not using Lombok
public class QuestionnaireService {
    private final QuestionnaireRepository questionnaireRepository;

    // ...

    public Questionnaire getQuestionnaireById(Long questionnaireId) {
        Questionnaire questionnaire = questionnaireRepository.findById(questionnaireId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new QuestionaireNotFoundException(questionnaireId));
        // Do whatever you want to do with the Questionnaire...
        return questionnaire;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I go with way 1 that you have mentioned. In case the object is not present, throw a validation exception or something. This approach also ensures that service layer is in charge of the logic and controller is just used your interacting with the outside world.